# Search, pagination and sorting not working in datatable

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, datatable

Currently, I am working on my datatable to display the detail from the database. I am using the php myadmin for the database. But it only manage to display the detail only but not the pagination, sorting and searching is not working. I have followed some other tutorials but it still doesn't work.

```
<?php  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "jiaen"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stock LEFT OUTER JOIN category ON stock.categoryid=category.categoryid order by stockCode";

//Execute connection
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
?>  
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
   <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</title>  
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>  
   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />  
   </script>
</head>  
<body>  
  <br /><br />  
  <div class="container">  
      <h3 align="center">Datatables Jquery Plugin with Php MySql and Bootstrap</h3>  
      <br />  
      <div class="table-responsive">  
           <table id="stock" class="table table-striped table-bordered" > 
              <thead>  
                 <tr>  
                    <td>Stock Code</td>  
                    <td>Stock Name</td> 
                     <td>Stock Category</td>  
                    <td>Quantity</td>  
                    <td>Price (RM)</td>  
                    <td>Action</td>  
                 </tr>  
              </thead> 
              <tbody>  
              <?php  
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
              {  
                 echo '  

                 <tr>  
                    <td>'.$row["stockCode"].'</td>  
                    <td>'.$row["stockName"].'</td>  
                    <td>'.$row["categoryName"].'</td>  
                    <td>'.$row["quantity"].'</td>  
                    <td>'.$row["price"].'</td>
                    <td><a href = "add.php?id='.$row["stockCode"].'">Stock In</a></td> 
                    <td><a href = "rnd.php?id='.$row["stockCode"].'">R&D</a></td> 
                    <td><a href = "remarkstock.php?id='.$row["stockCode"].'">Remark Stock</a></td> 
                    <td><a href = "modify.php?id='.$row["stockCode"].'">Modify</a></td> 
                    <td><a href = "delete.php?id='.$row["stockCode"].'">Delete</a></td>   
                 </tr> 

                 ';  
              }  
              ?>  
              </tbody> 
           </table>  

      </div>  
  </div> 

  //Javascript part for datatable  
  <script>  
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#stock').DataTable();
  } );
  </script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Checking the javascript console in your browser, do you see any errors related to datatables (or any other errors that might affect)?

Comment: You should add details regarding what you have tried and what did not work , errors or any other useful information

Comment: Please add more details about your problem. Right now we have no idea how to help you. You may want to look at this article on how to ask better questions on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "php myadmin" is not a database. MySQL is a database. phpMyAdmin is just one of many user interface programs which let you interact with a MySQL database. MySQL Workbench is another example of that. So is the MySQL command-line interface. Just noting that because I think it helps to understand the tools you're using and the role they play, that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<thead>` contains a `<tr>` which is full of `<td>` tags instead of `<th>` tags.

It has 6 tags, so your table will have 6 columns.

Your `<tbody>` on the other hand has 10 `<td>` tags inside each `<tr>` tag.

10 will not fit into 6.

Comment: Thankss,finally its works, but is there any ways to combine the row?

Comment: Either add more columns or combine the rows together. If you look at the datatables website there are plug ins for adding buttons, checkboxes etc

Comment: I have read about the checkbox but i wonder how it will connect to the database? does it use the datatable database itself or what?